# Godaddy SSL Certificates Install in NGINX Server | Failing

Tags: ssl-certificate, nginx-config, godaddy-api

I have requested SSL Certificate from `GoDaddy`, I got `Private Key` & `CSR` file, which downloaded as `TEXT` format.
[image]

I have modified file extensions as follows

```
**Original File Names**
firstcsrfile.txt
firstprivatekey.txt

**After Renaming File Names**
firstcsrfile.csr
firstprivatekey.key
```

domain.com.chained with below files downloaded from `GoDaddy` by selecting `other` option
[image]
From above files

- 1fbfa674f5fe68aa.crt to domain.com.crt
- gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt to intermediate.crt

```
cat domain.com.crt intermediate.crt > domain.com.chained.crt
```

My nginx.conf file

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name _;

        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com.chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/firstprivatekey.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried multiple times with various approaches but always same error

```
2022/10/24 13:51:20 [emerg] 1#1: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey("/etc/nginx/ssl/firstprivatekey.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey("/etc/nginx/ssl/firstprivatekey.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
```

I have followed few blogs from Godaddy and some random blogs
https://blog.yudiz.com/install-ssl-certificate-with-nginx/
Since last 6-7 days struggled a lot, and where I am doing mistakes not sure !!.

Comment: Be aware of **not publishing your private key**.

Comment: Yes sir, that was a random screen shot from internet. So, I have taken care for my data, it is just I wanted to simulate steps what I took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

First You should chose other and download,
after that In the downloaded file you will combine the .crt and bundle.crt file.

You will save it as a .pem in the /etc/nginx/ssl file path. I tried to do that as well.

Comment: You will end up with broken chain.
[![broken][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0YIN.png

Comment: After doing these, I took care of this process using "certbot" https://certbot.eff.org.

Answer (score 0):

You will end up with a broken chain if you do this.
[image: broken]